# css - targeting specific non-child decendents

Tags: html, css

I have the following markup:

```
<footer>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>content</li>
            <li><a target="_blank" href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a target="_blank" href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a target="_blank" href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div> 
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>Content</li>
            <li>Content</li>
            <li>Content</li>
            <li>Content</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</footer>
```

How can I target only the second `<ul>` with CSS without applying custom IDs and classes to my HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
footer > div:last-child > ul { /*styles*/ }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
footer div:nth-child(2) ul {
    background-color: green; /* For success */
}
```

```html
<footer>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>content</li>
            <li><a target="_blank" href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a target="_blank" href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a target="_blank" href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div> 
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>Content</li>
            <li>Content</li>
            <li>Content</li>
            <li>Content</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</footer>
```

That said, whenever possible I would encourage the class/ID route, because while it can be messy, it also allows you to rearrange items. It can also be slightly easier to troubleshoot when coming back to the site later, because it's clear from the markup what is styling them.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case `footer div:nth-of-type(2) ul` or `footer div:last-of-type ul`

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZBoONm

Answer (score 0):

Completing the collection of possible solutions:

```
footer div:nth-of-type(2) ul {
    color: red;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9uuqub2k